# How to store argparse values in variables?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to add command line options to my script, using the following code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('My program')
parser.add_argument('-x', '--one')
parser.add_argument('-y', '--two')
parser.add_argument('-z', '--three')

args = vars(parser.parse_args())

foo = args['one']
bar = args['two']
cheese = args['three']
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Also, how do I run it from the IDLE shell? I use the command
    'python myprogram.py -x foo -y bar -z cheese'
and it gives me a syntax error

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That will work, but you can simplify it a bit like this:

```
args = parser.parse_args()

foo = args.one
bar = args.two
cheese = args.three
```

Answer (score 7):

use `args.__dict__`

```
args.__dict__["one"]
args.__dict__["two"]
args.__dict__["three"]
```

Comment: I agree your solution is correct. And interesting,. At the same time, some people on SO get really cranky and downvote if a Python domain answer is not in what they see as acceptable pythonic form. Meh. Even though what is "acceptable" changes over time.

Comment: @DavidPointer is what it is I guess. Thanks for the pity votes :P

Comment: I don't know. After all the OP already used [**vars()**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/vars) which already returns the **__dict__**

Comment: It's "working" but it's to be avoided. The presence of the underscores is a **strong** hint that these methods are not intended to be invoked directly. Therefore, **yes, it's working, but no, it's not a good answer**. So I understand that some people downvote it.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to get the values of the arguments that is [suggested in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) is to use `vars` as you did and access the argument values by name:

```
argv = vars(args)

one = argv['one']
two = args['two']
three = argv['three']
```